# MediaWiki Visual Editor: trim new lines after HTML inserted as block node

Tags: javascript, mediawiki, visual-editor

First of all, I am no Javscript expert, I am just a general amateur programmer who knows how to copy-paste code and fix it for his needs.

Now, I am creating a gadget for Visual Editor in MW 1.39. I want a button for adding custom HTML tags inline.

This is my code so far:

```
ve.ui.BibliaCommand = function VeUiBibliaCommand() {
    ve.ui.BibliaCommand.super.call( this, 'Biblia' );
};
OO.inheritClass( ve.ui.BibliaCommand, ve.ui.Command );

ve.ui.BibliaCommand.prototype.execute = function ( surface ) {
    var model = surface.getModel(),
        doc = model.getDocument(),
        range = model.getSelection().getRange(),
        docRange = doc.shallowCloneFromRange( range );

    ve.init.target.getWikitextFragment( docRange, false ).done( function ( wikitext ) {
        var htmlfrag = model.getFragment().insertHtml('<bible>'+wikitext+'</bible>');
    } );
};

ve.ui.commandRegistry.register( new ve.ui.BibliaCommand() );

ve.ui.BibliaTool = function VeUiBibliaTool() {
    ve.ui.BibliaTool.super.apply( this, arguments );
};
OO.inheritClass( ve.ui.BibliaTool, ve.ui.Tool );
ve.ui.BibliaTool.static.name = 'Biblia';
ve.ui.BibliaTool.static.group = 'cite';
ve.ui.BibliaTool.static.icon = 'book';
ve.ui.BibliaTool.static.title = 'Biblia';
ve.ui.BibliaTool.static.commandName = 'Biblia';
ve.ui.toolFactory.register( ve.ui.BibliaTool );
```

It works and wraps the selected text in the desired tags. But it also inserts a newline before and after the wrapped selection.
Any suggestion on how I can remove these newlines?

Comment: Just an additional comment: If I add a checkpoint like this: `htmlfrag = model.getFragment().insertHtml('<bible>'+wikitext+'</bible>'); var checkvalue = htmlfrag.selection.range.from; alert(checkvalue)`, the alert shows *before* the new lines are inserted, and when i close the popup, the newlines are inserted and I see the text move. But the alertbox shows a value, so the insertHTML has already been executed.

Comment: Please post your comment as part of your question. People miss it if it stays in the comments.

Comment: the 'bible' tag is not recognized as a valid tag/node and is rendered as an alien node, there are two types of alien nodes, inline and block, this one is rendered as a block node, I don't know how to force it to be inline.  see: https://www.mediawiki.org/w/extensions/VisualEditor/lib/ve/demos/ve/desktop.html#!aliens

Comment: @Robis Koopmans thanks for the tip. I just solved it by "brute-forcing" a delete of the new lines after the insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. I did two replace transactions, in order to remove the newlines inserted before and after the HTLM (2 characters each, since they are CR/LF). It looks like this:

```
model.getFragment().insertHtml('<bible>'+wikitext+'</bible>');
var inicio = model.selection.range.from;
var mitransac = ve.dm.TransactionBuilder.static.newFromReplacement( doc,  new ve.Range( inicio, inicio+2 ), '' ) 
model.getFragment().change(mitransac);
var fin = model.selection.range.to;
var mitransac2 = ve.dm.TransactionBuilder.static.newFromReplacement( doc,  new ve.Range( fin-2, fin ), '' )
model.getFragment().change(mitransac2);
```